# Chamar função de script de teste [protractor]

Tags: javascript, testes, typescript, jasmine

Olá,
Possuo um arquivo que chama vários métodos de teste que criei com protractor, ele ficou mais ou menos assim:

```
import {MeuCadastro} from './MeuCadastro/MeuCadastro.spec';
import {Rotas} from './Rotas/rotas.spec';

let rotas: Rotas = new Rotas();
let meuCadastro: MeuCadastro = new MeuCadastro();

rotas.rotas();
meuCadastro.cadastro();
```

O problema é que o teste "Meu cadastro" não espera o de "rotas" finalizar, e acaba gerando um erro no expect dos testes.

Qual a melhor forma de usar esse métodos para que eles funcionem após o de cima ser finalizado?

Agradeço de antemão qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Usas callbacks, async/await ou promises?

Comment: Nunca utilizei, a melhor forma seria fazendo um callback?

Comment: É indiferente, depende do que estás mais habituado ou é mis prático para o código. Se esse `rotas.rotas();` fosse uma Promise podias fazer `rotas.rotas().then(meuCadastro.cadastro);`

Comment: Vou tentar com o promisse então e ver se funciona.